# How to set cookie using document.cookie in QML?

Tags: javascript, qt, cookies, qml

I have the following qml code

```
WebEngineView {
    id: _webView
    height: parent.height - 20
    width: parent.width - 20
    x: 10
    y: 10
    backgroundColor: "#e3e3e6"

    userScripts: WebEngineScript {
        injectionPoint: WebEngineScript.DocumentCreation
        sourceCode: "document.cookie = " + readyCookie
    }
    url: "http://example.com"
}
```

and I have a cookie in `readyCookie` variable. For example:

```
JSESSIONID=DUo6nBoJgAJAsimljT5PdfGc5hs97kSbb1LqMjgL.dfvdf-dfv-fdf; domain=something.ru; path=/
```

And I am trying to authorize in `url: "http://example.com"` string, using

```
userScripts: WebEngineScript {
            injectionPoint: WebEngineScript.DocumentCreation
            sourceCode: "document.cookie = " + readyCookie
        }
```

But this doesn't work. Cookies are right.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384703/user-vandalizes-and-deletes-a-question-with-close-votes-then-repost-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved:

```
userScripts: WebEngineScript {
    injectionPoint: WebEngineScript.DocumentCreation
    sourceCode: "document.cookie = \"" + readyCookie + "\""
}
```